# Show that the set $\Bbb N$ of natural numbers is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(\mathbb{R},d)$ be the metric space where

$$d(x,y)=|x−y| \; \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$$

Show that the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers is closed.

I tried the complement method but i don't know what to do after i let an element belong to the complement?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Please give us a little bit of context here.  What is the definition of a closed set from *your* textbook/notes? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @patrick stevens yes

Comment: Do you know that arbitrary union of open sets in $\Bbb R$ is also open in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes i know that but what it has to do with my question?

Comment: If you know that $(-\infty, 0)$ and each $(n, n+1)$ is open, then $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is the union of all of those open sets, so you're done. (For me, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$; if it's not for you, change $0$ to $1$.)

Comment: All clear , but how could i explain that these two intervals are open ?

Comment: What resource are you learning from? "Open intervals are open" should be one of the first things proved.

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few proofs:

---

To prove that it's closed, we will prove that it's complement is open. Consider the sets $S_i=B(i+1/2,1/2)$, where $B(x,r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. Each $S_i$ is open. $$(-\infty,0)\cup\left(\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} S_i\right)=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$$ so $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$ is the countable union of open sets and so it's open. Therefore complement of $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$, which is $\mathbb{N}$, is closed.

---

To prove that it's closed we will prove that it's complement is open. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$. We wish to show that there is an open ball centered at $x$ that contains no integers. Let $[x]$ denote the distance from $x$ to the nearest integer. This is either the fractional part of $x$ or one minus the fractional part of $x$, whichever is smaller. Then the ball $B(x,[x]/2)$ doesn't contain any integers. Thus $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$ is open and so $\mathbb{N}$ is closed.

---

To prove it's closed, we'll prove that every convergent sequence of elements in $\mathbb{N}$ had a limit in $\mathbb{N}$. Let $x_i\in\mathbb{N}$. For every $\epsilon>$ there exists an $N$ such that for $n>N$, $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$. Let $\epsilon=1/3$. Then whatever the limit is, there is only one natural number within a distance of $1/3$ of it. Call that integer $k$. Therefore there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N,a_n=k$ and so the sequence converges to $k$.

This last proof exploits the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is *discrete*. Any discrete set is closed by this argument.

Comment: I didn't understand what you write

Comment: @ShouqHere I accidentally hit submit too early. How's that

Comment: In the first proof you say Therefore it's complement N is closed. , that's mean that natural set is open , my question is how to proof it is closed .

Comment: @ShouqHere I mean "the complement of $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$, which is $\mathbb{N}$, is closed." Ill edit the wording to make that clear.

Comment: Okay and I have a question what is Si ? And what do you mean when you write the thing inside the B bracts

Comment: For an natural number $i$, $S_i$ is the ball of radius $1/2$ centered at $i+1/2$, which is the interval $(i,i+1)$. That's exactly what the notation with the $B$ means.

Answer (score 1):

The "complement method" will work: we need to show that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is open. ($\setminus$ is the set-difference symbol.)

Let $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$. We need to find an open interval - that is, an open ball - around $x$, which doesn't contain a natural.

Firstly, if $x < 0$ then I hope you can find an interval containing $x$ and no natural number yourself. So we only need to show it for positive $x$; say $x \in (n, n+1)$.

Can you give an interval containing the point $\frac{1}{2}$? How about the point $\frac{7}{8}$? How about $\frac{1}{1000}$? Does your method generalise to $x \in (0,1)$?

Now that you can find the answer for $x \in (0,1)$, add $n$ to it to obtain the answer for $x\in (n,n+1)$.

Comment: By R\N you mean R-N

Comment: And why we need to find an open interval around x ? I thought that we need to find an open ball

Comment: Correct: that's the set-difference symbol. I prefer $\setminus$ for the set-difference, because $X - Y$ could plausibly mean $\{x-y: x \in X, y \in Y \}$ in some contexts.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$, open intervals are precisely open balls.

Comment: I don't know how to find an interval that contains x and no natural number? a Hint ?

Comment: Give me any interval that contains $-3$.

Comment: (-infinity,-1)  why -3 ?

Comment: As a specific example of $x \in \mathbb{R}^{<0}$. Will that same trick work for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{<0}$?